# why is this error coming whenever am scrpping information from the website?

Tags: web-scraping

File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 802, in find_element_by_css_selector
return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: am not able to scrape information from the website and that's the error message poping out